# Adding Custom Endpoint in WordPress Rest API

Tags: plugins, custom-field, rest-api

I have been working on custom WordPress rest API Endpoint. Goal is to create a WordPress custom route in this route i want to get Category Id and convert it to Category Name. I have written the function but its returning null for the category Id. The function simply get the categories of the WordPress and register the route.How Can I get the all Categories Id and convert category Id into category name.

```
function w_categories()
{

    $categories = get_categories();

    $data = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $data[$i]['id'] = $category->ID;
        $i++;
    }

    return $data;
}
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('w/v2', 'trending', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'w_categories',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom endpoint for this. The built in categories endpoint can be used to get the category name from an ID: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#retrieve-a-category

Comment: Thanks. @JacobPeattie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead ID you should use cat_ID

```
$data[$i]['id'] = $category->cat_ID;
```

get_categories() return list of category objects with:

```
"term_id": 7,
"name": "default",
"slug": "default",
"term_group": 0,
"term_taxonomy_id": 7,
"taxonomy": "category",
"description": "",
"parent": 0,
"count": 11,
"filter": "raw",
"cat_ID": 7,
"category_count": 11,
"category_description": "",
"cat_name": "Analiza",
"category_nicename": "default",
"category_parent": 0
```